# Prolog - Count the number of leaves in a tree

Tags: tree, count, prolog

If I have a tree that for example looks like this:

```
tree3(b(l(1),b(l(2),l(3)))).
```

How would I write a program that counts the number of leaves?
I want it to look something like this when it's been used:

```
?- tree3(T), count_leaves(T, N).

N = 3,
T = b(l(1),b(l(2),l(3)))
```

I'd love any help!

Comment: I tried:
count_leaves(empty, 0).
count_leaves(tree(L,_, R), Total_Size):-
 count_leaves(L, Left_Size),
 count_leaves(R, Right_Size),
 Total_Size is Left_Size + Right_Size + 1.
But it just gives me no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
count_leaves(l(_), 1).
count_leaves(b(B1, B2), N) :- count_leaves(B1, N1), count_leaves(B2, N2), N is N1 + N2.
```

Basically, tree that is just a leaf has one leaf. If the tree starts with a branch, recurse into both branches and add the results.

Your solution gives you `no`, because nothing will match against `empty`. And even if you fixed that, you wouldn't be counting leaves, but inner nodes.

Comment: Could you help me with something else too?
I now want to write a program that puts the information from the leaves in a list.

I tried doing this:
leaves(l(_), [_]).
leaves(b(B1, B2), [L]):-
 leaves(B1, [L1]),
 leaves(B2, [L2]).
append(L1, L2, L).

But it gives me L=[_A]. Why is that?

Comment: You should ask another question about that.

Comment: I'm also new to prolog, the only thing that seems strange with your solution is the first line. I would have written it `count_leaves(l(_), N) :- N is 1.`. Can you explain how your solution works @svick?

Comment: That's just how Prolog works. When you “call” `count_leaves(l(a), N).`, it tries to match it with the first clause. The first parameter matches (unifying the anonymous variable `_` with `a`, which is ignored). The second parameter matches too, unifying `N` with `1`, which is what we wanted. Your solution is just somewhat longer way to write the same. (I would also use `=` instead of `is`, but that's yet another topic.)